# Regex math a string only contain two words in Elixir

Tags: regex, elixir

I want to match a string to contain **only** two words, like a `user:passwd` format, my suggesting is

```
Regex.match?(%r/^\w:\w$/, string)
```

But it doesn't works.... Could someone helps me?

I want these examples to match: `a:b` `aa:23bw`;

and these examples not to match: `a: b`, `a:b  c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `+` after your `\w`s.  I'm not familiar with Elixer, but perhaps

```
Regex.match?(%r/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, string)
```

This is basic Regex.

Comment: Perfect, `Regex.match?(%r/^\w+:\w+$/, string)` would also work. Keep in mind though `\w` also matches underscores.